# Total distance of route using Leaflet routing machine in rMaps/rCharts

Tags: leaflet, shiny, rcharts, rmaps

I would like to produce a shiny app that asks for two addresses, maps an efficient route, and calculates the total distance of the route. This can be done using the [Leaflet Routing Machine](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/geocoders/) using the javascript library, however I would like to do a bunch of further calculations with the distance of the route and have it all embedded in a shiny app.

You can produce the map using rMaps by following this demo by Ramnathv [here](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/9998388). But I'm not able to pull out the total distance travelled even though I can see that it has been calculated in the legend or controller. There exists another discussion on how to do this using the javascript library - see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110313/how-to-get-the-total-km-of-route-using-leaflet-routing-machine-api). They discuss using this javascript code:

```
alert('Distance: ' + routes[0].summary.totalDistance);
```

Here is my working code for the rMap. If anyone has any ideas for how to pull out the total distance of a route and store it, I would be very grateful. Thank you!

```
# INSTALL DEPENDENCIES IF YOU HAVEN'T ALREADY DONE SO
library(devtools)
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts@dev")
install_github("ramnathv/rMaps")

# CREATE FUNCTION to convert address to coordinates
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)

construct.geocode.url <- function(address, return.call = "json", sensor = "false") {
  root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/"
  u <- paste(root, return.call, "?address=", address, "&sensor=", sensor, sep = "")
  return(URLencode(u))
}

gGeoCode <- function(address,verbose=FALSE) {
  if(verbose) cat(address,"\n")
  u <- construct.geocode.url(address)
  doc <- getURL(u)
  x <- fromJSON(doc)
  if(x$status=="OK") {
    lat <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
    lng <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
    return(c(lat, lng))
  } else {
    return(c(NA,NA))
  }
}

# GET COORDINATES
x <- gGeoCode("Vancouver, BC")
way1 <- gGeoCode("645 East Hastings Street, Vancouver, BC")
way2 <- gGeoCode("2095 Commercial Drive, Vancouver, BC")

# PRODUCE MAP
library(rMaps)
map = Leaflet$new()
map$setView(c(x[1], x[2]), 16)
map$tileLayer(provider = 'Stamen.TonerLite')

mywaypoints = list(c(way1[1], way1[2]), c(way2[1], way2[2]))

map$addAssets(
  css = "http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css",
  jshead = "http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"
)

routingTemplate = "
 <script>
 var mywaypoints = %s
 L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng.apply(null, mywaypoints[0]),
    L.latLng.apply(null, mywaypoints[1])
  ]
 }).addTo(map);
 </script>"

map$setTemplate(
  afterScript = sprintf(routingTemplate, RJSONIO::toJSON(mywaypoints))
)
# map$set(width = 800, height = 800)
map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a route via the google maps api. The returned data frame will have distance info. Just sum up the legs for total distance.

```
library(ggmap)
x <- gGeoCode("Vancouver, BC")
way1txt <- "645 East Hastings Street, Vancouver, BC"
way2txt <- "2095 Commercial Drive, Vancouver, BC"
route_df <- route(way1txt, way2txt, structure = 'route')
dist<-sum(route_df[,1],na.rm=T) # total distance in meters
#
qmap(c(x[2],x[1]), zoom = 12) +
   geom_path(aes(x = lon, y = lat),  colour = 'red', size = 1.5, data = route_df, lineend = 'round')
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you! Although, I wish that I could interact with the map more (e.g., zoom in and out) and have the map position itself and zoom depending on the route. Also, qmap does seem a bit slow, which may be problematic when packaged in Shiny. But otherwise, this does exactly what I need.

Comment: I just added the qmap as a quick example plot. But yeah, it is limited.  You should be able to take the coordinate info from the route_df and plot a similar line on a leaflet map.

Comment: That's a good idea, re: take route_df and plot in leaflet. Thanks!